# JavaFX app appears under javaw.exe in windows Task Manager. How can i make it appear as an independent application

Tags: java, javafx-8

I created a small javaFX app that draws some pie charts and creates some reports etc. When I launch my app it appears under Javaw.exe in Windows Task Manager instead of appearing it as an independent app. How can I make it appear as an independent application in task manager and windows processes list?

In the below screenshot, "MyApp" appears under "Java(TM) Platform SE Binary"
I want it to appear independently like how the Scene Builder.exe appears in the same screenshot.

**Screenshot of my task manager**
[image]

I have tried launching the app from jar file and creating an exe using Launch4j, but it always appear under javaw.exe in task manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Launch4j dropped support for custom renaming of processes.](https://sourceforge.net/p/launch4j/bugs/95/)

However, the name of the parent node displayed in task manager is the JVM you are using. You can rename the JVM manually (you'll find that recommended all over the place), but **that is not a good solution**, especially for production software.

The best method I've found is to use [Apache Procrun](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html) to wrap the program in a windows service. The official documentation lacks thorough examples, so I strongly recommend [this tutorial](https://joerglenhard.wordpress.com/2012/05/29/build-windows-service-from-java-application-with-procrun/). It is a tad dated (2013), but still works. The author even made an example github project.